# How does Wordpress Post Locking mechanism know, that a user stopped editing a post?

Tags: php, wordpress

From playing around with the Post locking mechanism, i realized two things: Wordpress sends an ajax request every 15 seconds or so, to "refresh" the lock. The response can indicate if the post is locked by another admin. Secondly, Wordpress keeps the identity of the last editing admin, in the wp_postmeta table(it also stores a time stamp).

What i can't figure out though, is how exactly Wordpress deduces the "state" of the post, using this mechanism. It doesn't seem to be using any Websocket, yet Wordpress would figure out you're "done" editing the post, even if u abruptly shut down your browser.

Can some one shed a light on this issue? I will mention that i didn't look into the Wordpress code. I just tried to figure out the logic of the mechanism, by looking at the network tab, and the mysql database.

Comment: When the last updated state of the editor is older than the heartbeat time it becomes stale and thus knows the next ping it gets is a new session. I realise that is just a very broad overview but it is as simple as no ping in x amount of time = nobody editing it. It doesn't necessarily have a 'close session' trigger that tells WP you are done though.